# How to align reference code?

Tags: listings, alignment, ref

I want to add reference to my c++ project, but it doesn't seem quite right. The code doesn't has any alignment, and it get cropped with the paper. It look like this:

[image: how it looks]

I use this to link my code to latex:

```
    \lstset{language=C++,
        numberstyle=\ttfamily,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
        stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
        commentstyle=\color{gray}\ttfamily,
        morecomment=[l][\color{magenta}]{\#}
    }

    \lstinputlisting[label={foo},caption={\textit{Source code} program}, language={C++}]{main.cpp}
```

How to add alignment to the code?

Comment: I think you are looking for the `breaklines` option, which be default is `false`.  The documentation of the `listings` package provides further options to control these automatic line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about combining the following 2 improvements?

(i) as pointed out by Andrew Swann: wrap lines using the `breaklines` option, which be default is `false`. ("The documentation of the listings package provides further options to control these automatic line breaks")

(ii) wrap the whole listing inside a `\small` environment (or even `\tiny`), which may make it easier to read and visually nicer

PS This is posted as an Answer because I'm a newbie and don't yet have privileges to comment, otherwise I'd make it a comment!